# Organise CMake tests by folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, googletest

I'm working on a C++ project which uses CMake to run tests using GTest.

TL;DR how do I get the testing pane of VSCode to reflect the directory structure of the tests?

I have several tests written, in a directory structure something like

```
base/
├─ tests/
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  ├─ my_tests/
│  │  ├─ maths/
│  │  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  │  │  ├─ maths_tests.cpp
│  │  ├─ util/
│  │  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  │  │  ├─ util_tests.cpp
├─ CMakeLists.txt
```

In `base/CMakeLists.txt` I have a bunch of `add_subdirectory` calls to add the test directories. In `base/tests/CMakeLists.txt` I fetch GoogleTest.

The problem I'm facing is that in the "Testing" pane of VSCode, all of the tests are listed directly under the `base` directory rather than being listed under the full directory. (The view mode is set to tree, not list). How do I make sure that the tests' folders are included in the tree view?

Comment: How do you actually *add* the tests? Do you use gtest_discover_tests or gtest_add_tests?

Comment: @André gtest_discover_tests